# Code for setting Alarm Manager to fire on certain day of the week (android)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

So I have written this code for getting AlarmManager to fire on a specified day of the week.  Trouble is, I can't really sit around and wait for the notification to pop up tomorrow to see if I got the code right!  Can someone take a look and see if what I wrote makes sense please?

(day is an int (1-7 to represent Sunday-Saturday))

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != day)
     {
         if(day > calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
         {
             calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
         }

         if(day < calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
         {
             calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
             if(day > 1)
             {
                 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7 - (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - day));
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a unit test for your code and test it with different dates, days of the week. Then you can be sure that you are calculating the alarm fire time correctly. Any other problems would be with the AlarmManager itself, which is outside of your control.

Comment: could you go into a little more detail?  i guess i could print out some property of the Calendar class which could give me the answer?

Comment: i did just that, and it seems like my code is working just fine.  thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines of an automated [JUnit](http://junit.org/) test, where you compare expected values with actual output. If you really tested with enough different inputs to cover all possible cases, manual testing using logging works too.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the date/time on the phone to make it think it's the day of the alarm?